# segue/push to different view controller from IBAction function?

Tags: swift, push, viewcontroller, ibaction, sigabrt

I am trying to push to the next viewcontroller programatically, such that I can save data in core data and then push to the next view controller. Basically when I tap a button with an IBAction, it will do all this. However, I am getting a thread 1 SIGABRT error whenever I use this code in my IBAction func:

```
    @IBAction func onPlusTapped(){

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Course", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Course"
        }
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "New", style: .default){ (_) in
            let course = alert.textFields!.first?.text!
            print(course)

            let coursy = Course(context: PersistenceService.context)
            coursy.name = course
            PersistenceService.saveContext()
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        // jump to next view controller
        segway()

    }

    func segway(){
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "viewcontroller", bundle: nil)
    let balanceViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewcontroller") as! ViewController
    self.present(balanceViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you jumping segway and present alert at the same time? shouldn't you put `segway()` inside your alert action?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to jump to your next viewController once `Course` saved, you have to call the `func segway()` in the `UIAlertAction` completion block.

Example:

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "New", style: .default){ (_) in
            let course = alert.textFields!.first?.text!
            print(course)

            let coursy = Course(context: PersistenceService.context)
            coursy.name = course
            PersistenceService.saveContext()
            // jump to next view controller
            segway()

        }
```

Also double check your storyboard name and balanceViewController's identifier is "viewcontroller".

Comment: I have done so, except I get the same error. what should be named "view"? the first view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you jumping segway() and present alert at the same time? shouldn't you put segway() inside your alert action?

Please see the following code.

```
@IBAction func onPlusTapped() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Course", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Course"
        }
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "New", style: .default){ (_) in
            let course = alert.textFields!.first?.text!
            print(course)

            let coursy = Course(context: PersistenceService.context)
            coursy.name = course
            PersistenceService.saveContext()

             // jump to next view controller
            segway()
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func segway() {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "viewcontroller", bundle: nil)
        let balanceViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewcontroller") as! ViewController
        self.present(balanceViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I have done so, except I get the same error. what should be named "view"? the first view controller?